# How to apply patch to rt2x00 driver for Ralink RT5390 support

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, hp, ralink

I have a Pavilion dm1, with a [known issue with the rt2x00 driver](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-closed@lists.debian.org/msg327720.html). There is a [one line patch](http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com/pipermail/users_rt2x00.serialmonkey.com/2011-June/003942.html) that fixes the issue. How do I apply it?

Comment: @TimMcNamara Have a bounty! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one line patch simply shows you that you would need to edit the `rt2800pci.c` file from the linux header source files and add,

`#ifdef CONFIG_RT2800PCI_RT53XX`

`{ PCI_DEVICE(0x1814, 0x5390) },`

`{ PCI_DEVICE(0x1814, 0x539f) },`

`#endif`

lines to the file and recompile the header again to get the drivers to work correctly.

Comment: How do I recompile the driver without affecting apt?

Comment: Run the following command:

`$ sudo ./configure`

Then run:

`$ sudo ./make`

And finally:

`$ sudo ./make install`

Comment: Those are fine instructions for compiling, but how do I avoid conflicting with `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: This will only affect it if the linux header files have a major update. You can always recompile the headers with the drivers. I know that does not sound productive, but that is the way how linux is. Not linux's fault, just the manufacturer of the NIC. They need to be proactive and be able to support the NIC.